# MySQL string quotation for REPLACE()

Tags: mysql, sql, string, replace

I have problem using REPLACE() function on specific data. It doesn't match string occurrence that it should replace.

The string I want to replace is the following.

> s:54:"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection_elements

It is stored in the following field

```
`definitions` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:object)',
```

Here is the LIKE request which matches all rows that contain the string (notice `\0` on the string):

```
SELECT `definitions` 
FROM `entity_type` 
WHERE `definitions` LIKE '%s:54:"\0Doctrine\\\\Common\\\\Collections\\\\ArrayCollection\0_elements%'
```

At the same time when I run the following request I get '0 rows affected' message and nothing is replaced:

```
UPDATE `entity_type`
    SET `definitions` = REPLACE(
        `definitions`, 
        's:54:"\0Doctrine\\\\Common\\\\Collections\\\\ArrayCollection\0_elements', 
        's:53:"\0Doctrine\\\\Common\\\\Collections\\\\ArrayCollection\0elements'
    );
```

How should I modify the string to make REPLACE() match the text I need and replace it?

PS: Please don't blame me for what I'm trying to replace. it is not my fault :-)

Comment: `ArrayCollection_elements` != `ArrayCollection\0_elements` this is not clear, also there is some ambiguity with `\ `

Comment: When I post a string as a text the \0 is obviously not displayed but it is there. I used the same amount of slashes as in LIKE

Comment: Can you please share a part of table data so that I can recreate the situation?

Comment: I tried It normally with one of my tables in SQL it is working fine, there could be some flaw with your data in the table.

Comment: Try something like [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/125b88/7).

Comment: **@Stepashka**: When there is only *one* char difference in source and target strings, why can't you just replace that char instead?

Answer (score 0):

If your "where condition" works, you can try with:

```
UPDATE `entity_type`
    SET `definitions` = REPLACE(REPLACE(
        `definitions`, 
        's:54:', 
        's:53:'),'ArrayCollection_elements','ArrayCollectionelements')
where `definitions` LIKE '%s:54:"\0Doctrine\\\\Common\\\\Collections\\\\ArrayCollection\0_elements%';
```